# mpeg dash live stream example

Tags: live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am working on MPEG-DASH Live Sreaming and am trying to find a test URL of a live streaming content. So far I've been able to find many VOD content, but not much for live streaming. Does anyone have a test live stream URL?

Comment: Why is this off topic?

Answer (score 8):

We use an public MPEG-DASH livestream on our demo pages at http://www.dash-player.com/demo/live-streaming-dvr/ and http://www.bitcodin.com/live-streaming/. It comes together with representations up to 1080p and is distributed via an CDN, thus worldwide pretty well usable. This stream is also available as HLS. You can use it via HTTP and HTTPS

MPEG-DASH MPD: http://bitlivedemo-a.akamaihd.net/mpds/stream.php?streamkey=bitcodin

HLS M3U8: https://bitlivedemo-a.akamaihd.net/m3u8s/bitcodin.m3u8

Comment: it is interesting: your bitcodin manifest plays on your player, but doesn't play on reference dashif player.

Comment: Yes, the dash.js player does not support all MPDs of all vendors out there. But it should be easy to find a MPD configuration that plays that livestream with dash.js as well.

Comment: It seems that it is wrong to say about "DASH"  We need to speak about "DASH for bitcodin v1.5"  or "DASH for dash.js 1.3 and Chrome 37".

Comment: The DASH URL http://bitlivedemo-a.akamaihd.net/mpds/stream.php?streamkey=bitcodin seems to have one error in the representation params for 1080p content. The height attribute is wrong.

Comment: The [URL of DASH MPD](http://bitlivedemo-a.akamaihd.net/mpds/stream.php?streamkey=bitcodin) is broken, so the video is not played

Comment: Here is an bunch of demo streams: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash-live-source-simulator/wiki/Test-URLs

Comment: @yuliskov 's link works. The answer doesn't

Comment: all the links in the answer are broken. @yuliskov 's link is to mpd files which dont do anything in firefox except ask you to save them, except one site which has a jasvascript error. since this is literally a live video streaming discussion i doubt that any links will stay good for very long.